# jpegtran optimize without changing filename

Tags: linux, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I need to optimize some images, but not change their name.

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize image.jpg > image.jpg
```

However, this seems to create an filesize of 0. When i do it to a different filename, the size is still exactly the same.

Comment: See this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835351/jpegtran-whole-directory

Answer (score 33, accepted):

how about:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile image.jpg image.jpg
```

I'm not a shell expert by any means, but I think that with your original command, as soon as it is executed, the redirect is set up which overwrites your image.jpg. Then when jpegtran tries to read it in it finds an empty file.

Comment: Clement please provide details, this works for me (and apparently for the poster.)

Comment: Well, Jpegtran only accept 1 parameter, the original filename. Giving him a 2nd parameter, like you do, makes him throw an exception. This code would work on windows, but not on linux. You'd have to use `jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile image.jpg > newimage.jpg` as OP said, but then, it's not a file replacement. Precision: I tested it on Ubuntu/Jpegtran version 8b , maybe other version would work with your code.

Comment: Also the `jpegtran -optimize image.jpg > image.jpg` doesn't work, as linux **first** clear and recreate the image.jpg (`> image.jpg`), **and only then** launch the command (`jpegtran -optimize image.jpg`).

Comment: Clement I think you must have something wrong with your system, this works fine for me on OSX as well as Ubuntu with Jpegtran 8b. Try copy and pasting the exact line from my answer and please post your output if it doesn't execute properly.

Comment: Hi Clement, in your command you are missing the switch -outfile. Try this: jpegtran -opt -copy none -outfile acr-jpeg-01.jpg acr-jpeg-01.jpg

Comment: Oh gosh just realized that I typed the command wrong, **about 5 times** -_-. This is working, I'm sorry. I edited the answer to be able to upvote your answer =)

Comment: A heads-up for anyone else looking at this, it seems this works with version 8d of jpegtran but NOT 6b.

Answer (score 11):

I use this script. Works flawlessly. I hope this helps.

https://gist.github.com/iimos/7424025

```
#! /bin/sh

EXTENSIONS="jpe?g"

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    DIR="`pwd`"
else
    DIR="$1"
fi

# Optimize JPEG images
find "$DIR" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*\.($EXTENSIONS)\$" -type f | xargs -I{} jpegtran -optimize -progressive -outfile "{}.optimized" "{}"

# Rename xxx.jpg.optimized -> xxx.jpg
find "$DIR" -name '*.optimized' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do 
    chown $(stat -c "%U:%G" "${file%.optimized}") "$file"
    chmod $(stat -c "%a" "${file%.optimized}") "$file"
    mv -f "$file" "${file%.optimized}"; 
done
```

Usage 1:

```
optimize-images.sh /images/dir
```

Usage 2:

```
cd /images/dir
optimize-images.sh
```

Comment: Thanks but the script does not work when run inside directories with spaces in their name (it's bad but it happens).

Comment: @kursus Fixed. Thank you for report

Comment: @iMos Thank you! you save my day! #!bin/bash would fix 'Illegal option -d' error

Answer (score 2):

I did it in three lines:

```
jpegtran -optimize image.jpg > image.jpg-opt
cp image.jpg-opt image.jpg
rm image.jpg-opt
```

Works well.

[edit:] This works only for one file at a time.

Comment: jpegtran -optimize image.jpg > image.jpg-opt && mv image.jpg-opt image.jpg

Answer (score 2):

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive -optimize -outfile filename filename
```

For comprehensive optimization: **-copy none** tells jpegtran to suppress all comments and other excess baggage present in  the source jpeg, **progressive** generates a progressive jpeg, **-optimize** performs the actual optimizations, and **-outfile** sets the output file name. The last parameter is the input file name: if they are the same, your file is optimized in place.

**Edit:** you might want to also try mozjpeg, according to this article on lossless jpeg compression tools http://blarg.co.uk/blog/comparison-of-jpeg-lossless-compression-tools

Comment: Adding `-progressive` is a good idea for performance reasons - http://blog.patrickmeenan.com/2013/06/progressive-jpegs-ftw.html

Answer (score 1):

Without sponge, another alternative with lower HDD or SSD writing access is to use the /dev/shm to save the temporary file and then overwrite it locally right away.

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize image.jpg > /dev/shm/tmp.jpg &&  cat /dev/shm/tmp.jpg > ./image.jpg
```

The concept can be easily adapted into any script, perhaps with caveats about the temporary filename not being the same, in order to avoid collisions if there are multiple instances running at the same time. It's possibly interesting to think about some unique filename pattern generation scheme, perhaps something along the lines of `${originalfilename}-jpgtrantmp-$$`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if `-outfile` is not supported:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize image.jpg | sponge image.jpg
```

`sponge` is part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).