# jpegtran whole directory

Tags: command-line, directory, putty, libjpeg

I want to optimize the whole test folder with jpg images from a command line.
I found this but it doesn't work:

```
cd /home/site/html/update/test/
find . -exec jpegtran -optimize "{}" "{}.opti.jpg" "{}" \;
```

I want to overwrite the existing images.

Suggestions?

Answer:

```
find /img/path -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile {} {} \;
```

Comment: Look here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12066282/502860

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursivly use JpegTran (command line) to optimise all files in subdirs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831293/how-to-recursivly-use-jpegtran-command-line-to-optimise-all-files-in-subdirs)

Comment: Please post an answer as an answer. If you found a duplicate for your question, answer it there instead of linking to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
find /img/path -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile {} {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is solved here pretty earlier but **talking about Python approach:**

```
import subprocess
for image_name in arr:
    subprocess.call(["jpegtran", "-your", "-instructions"])
```

Let's say your instruction is something like:

`jpegtran -optimize -progressive -scans script_new.txt -outfile progressive.jpg original.jpg`

So your instruction will be like:

```
subprocess.call(["jpegtran", "-optimize", "-progressive", "-scans", f"{scan_name}.txt", "-outfile", name_progressive, name_original])
```

For your convenience, name_progressive, name_original and scan_name are variables and concept f-string is used.